# DataGridViewColumn ToolTip as balloon, not default tooltip square

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

It is possible for every column header in a DataGridView to set a different tooltip text that will show in a **balloon** tooltip, not default square design?

Comment: Why not? You add a ToolTip to the form and set it IsBalloon = true; Then you can e.g. use dgv.MouseHover and a HitTest to find out if and which column header is under the cursor and set a suitable  tooltip text and show it..

Comment: You can try to set the tooltip in the `CellMouseEnter` event. Something like `if (e.RowIndex == -1) { toolTip1.IsBalloon = true; toolTip1.Show($"ToolTip on Column {e.ColumnIndex}", this, this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position), 500); }`. I doubt you'll have a great effect.

Comment: Yes, you are right Jimi, the effect is not so great, as that little tip is not onto the mouse tip.

Comment: Maybe I figure out how to show it with balloon tip in center of the cell, no matter where mouse point were on enter over the cell...